# Centroid given a list of vectors

Tags: vector, lisp, common-lisp

I have to calculate the mean vector given a list of vectors such as this one

`'((2 3 56) (22 45 34) (21 2 23) (4 8 3) (4 4 1) (4 4 5))`

In short words I have to find the centroid given a list of lists.

```
(defun vsum (x y)
 (cond ((not (= (list-length x) (list-length y))) (error "dimension error!"))
   ((null (first x)) NIL)
       (t (cons (+ (first x) (first y)) (vsum (rest x) (rest y))))))
```

I already created this simple function but I'm having major troubles in getting it used in a recursive way (I prefer it against the loop) to accomplish my task. I need that to be dimension agnostic, too (e.g. vectors of size 2 or 3 mostly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case there is no need of loops or recursion, only primitive functionals:

```
(defun centroid (list)
  (when list
    (let ((list-length (length list))
          (dimension (length (first list))))
      (unless (every (lambda (v) (= (length v) dimension)) (rest list))
        (error "Dimension error!"))
      (mapcar (lambda (x) (/ x list-length))
              (reduce (lambda (x y) (mapcar #'+ x y)) list)))))
```

The formula used is that for a finite set of points (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points)).

First a check is done to see if all the vectors have the same dimension (the part with `every`), then the sum is calculated with the `(reduce (lambda (x y) (mapcar #'+ x y)) list)` part, and finally each coordinate is divided by the number of points (the `mapcar` part).

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly well. I thought about applying the same recursion model I made with the _sum_ function above and I didn't give the right weight to the _mapcar_ keyword.

Comment: APPLY has a limited argument size. Don't use APPLY for list processing. APPLY is thought as a mechanism for function calls with computed arglists.

Comment: `(reduce (lambda (x y) (mapcar #'+ x y)) list)`

Comment: If we are going to check all these errors, we should also check for an input empty list. In this case, the centroid could be a vector of all zeros: but we don't know how many dimensions it must have. I think in this case what the above code will do is try to call the `(lambda (x y) ..)` with no arguments, resulting in a hard to understand error message. (The division by `list-length`, which is zero, won't be reached).

Comment: @Kaz if the list is empty the result of the previous function is nil, since the body is enclosed in a `when`, and this seems to me a reasonable result (rather than a zero vector, which is actually a point that could be generated by some other input).

Answer (score 3):

> I prefer it against the loop

But it makes no sense. Recursive functions are harder to use and can cause stack overflows.

Your `vsum` function is better written as

```
(defun vsum (x y)
  (assert (= (length x) (length y))   ; both lists of equal length
      (x y)                           ; the lists, can be repaired
    "Dimension error")                ; the error message
  (mapcar #'+ x y))                   ; simple mapping
```

Above version is

- better to use interactively in case of an error, due to the use of ASSERT
- shorter
- clearer
- without stack overflow problems for *larger* input lists

The `mapcar` expression can be written using `loop` as:

```
(loop for x1 in x and y1 in y
      collect (+ x y))
```

Which is still clearer and shorter than your recursive code.